# Run grunt server with various browsers

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Is it possible to specify a particular browser (besides the OS' default) in the gruntfile or at the command prompt? E.g. "grunt server firefox" or the like. My default browser is Chrome, but I want to test/develop my site in multiple browsers. I am using GruntJS within Yeoman.

Bryan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Quick Answer

In `Gruntfile.js` you can add an `app` parameter:

```
open: {
  server: {
    url: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>',
    app: 'firefox'
  }
},
```

Pull request: https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-open/pull/7

Commit: https://github.com/GabLeRoux/grunt-open/commit/6f2c7069767e58160ec96aaaa8fa20ed210ba183

---

#### Command Line Parameters

It is possible to pass command line parameters in the app string, such as `app: "chromium-browser --incognito"` - @bk11425

Comment: Sorry to be late in replying, but thanks for the update! It works great.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I also noticed that one can pass command line parameters in the app string, such as `app: "chromium-browser --incognito"`.

Comment: I can launch the app in any browser with your fix, but it's also launched in the default browser as well (along with targeted browser). Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Nilesh What does your `open` config object look like and how is the task calling it?

Comment: @Nilesh: Could you add the grunt console output to the fiddle?

Comment: @slamborne: I figured it out. It turns out that my grunt file had 'livereload' task that was opening app in default browser. Setting 'open:false' inside livereload did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of grunt connect: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect

You can use:

```
    open: {
        target: 'http://localhost:8000', // target url to open
        appName: 'open', // name of the app that opens, ie: open, start, xdg-open
        callback: function() {} // called when the app has opened
    }
```

i.e. appName: 'Google Chrome'

Answer (score 2):

While the answers in here helped fix my occurrence of the problem, as someone who's not very familiar with grunt, I had a hard time figuring just exactly **where** I was supposed to put the "open:" stanza in my Gruntfile.js.  It took me about three three tries for me to find the right spot (e.g I tried directly under 'grunt.initConfig' and under 'connect: options:' to no effect)

I'm using the Gruntfile.js as generated by the  [standard angular yeoman generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular).

I'm posting where I put it in this file just to give a little more "context" for anyone in a similar predicament.

Here is the relevant snippet of the Gruntfile.js:

```
// ...
The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      //open: true, <- original line, comment out
      // add this
      open: {
        //target: 'http://localhost:9000', <- this works too
        target: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>',
        appName: 'firefox'
      },
      // end add
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  test: {
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

The grunt server task has almost nothing to do with the browser, it just starts a static server for you to connect to and preview your app. You could theoretically use any browser you want to connect to `http://localhost:8080/`

To clarify based on the poster's comment:

`grunt-open` is a different task than grunt-server: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-open.`grunt-open` uses `node-open` which just defaults to the default `open` task for darwin or `start` for win32: https://github.com/jjrdn/node-open#how-it-works

So, to answer, whatever application you have specified to open `.html` files (or whatever you're opening) will open with this task.

Comment: That is true, but in the gruntfile, there is a setting that calls the default browser: `open: {
            server: {
                path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
            }
        },` What I want to know is if there is a way for it to call a specific browser or if it is beholden to the OS default browser settings

Comment: And it looks like I'm not the first one who asked about this: [https://github.com/onehealth/grunt-open/issues/3]