# How to make GruntJS start Chrome with flags set

Tags: gruntjs

When I run the command `grunt build`, I would like it to start Chrome automatically with the flags `--disable-extensions` and `--disable-web-security` set. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect
[Run grunt server with various browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430291/run-grunt-server-with-various-browsers)

```
...
open: {
    target: "http://localhost:3002",
    appName: "open -n -a Google\\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/tmp/junk"
},
...
```

I don't know grunt that well, but this is from a conversation from my co-workers. Hope it helps. (of course, the "open" command is specifically for OSX, for windows you would point to the google chrome.exe, and linux would simply be "google-chrome". --user-data-dir=/tmp/junk allows you to open up the browser as a new user.)

Comment: hmmm, idk what my issue is exactly, but jsHint complains when I do this (it doesn't like the '\'). `Bad or unnecessary escaping.` `appName: 'open -n -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security'`

Comment: use double quotes around the string instead of single quotes maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me on my Mac

```
  open: {
    appName: "hiddenBrowser", // some unexisted name of app
    callback: function(){
        var exec = require('child_process').exec;
        exec('open -a "Google Chrome Canary" --args --disable-web-security "http://localhost:3000"')
    }
  }
```

---

Based on code of `npm-open` and `grunt-contrib-open`, all what you write in appName goes in quotes. For example:

```
{
  target: 'http://localhost:3000', // target url to open
  appName: 'Google Chrome --args --disable-web-security', // name of the app that opens, ie: open, start, xdg-open
  callback: function() {} // called when the app has opened
}
```

Will be calling like

```
open -n "Google Chrome --args --disable-web-security" "http://localhost:3000"
```

So I did a trick and call my browser in callback.